# PNGs for different Themes cause InflateException

Tags: android

I have an App with two different color themes (a dark and a light theme). I one part of my app, I am using a png as background for a widget, which should have different colors in the two themes.

styles.xml:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        ...
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.DARK" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="my_png">@drawable/my_png_theme_dark</item>
        <item name="my_png2">@drawable/my_png2_theme_dark</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.DARK" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="my_png">@drawable/my_png_theme_light</item>
        <item name="my_png2">@drawable/my_png2_theme_light</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

attrs.xml:

```
<resources>
    <attr name="my_png" format="reference"/>
    <attr name="my_png2" format="reference"/>
</resources>
```

drawable/my_background.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="?attr/my_png" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="?attr/my_png2" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

layout/my_activity.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/my_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:button="@drawable/my_background"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I provide this png in `values-mdpi`, `values-hdpi`, `values-xhdpi` and `values-xxhdpi`.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp.myapp/com.myapp.myapp.ui.activities.MyActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #76: Binary XML file line #76: Error inflating class CheckBox
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2793)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2864)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1567)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #76: Binary XML file line #76: Error inflating class CheckBox
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #76: Error inflating class CheckBox
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.myapp.myapp:drawable/my_background with resource ID #0x7f080099
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/my_background.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f080099
```

I do the same with vector drawables in different colors, which works perfectly. I can't figure out why it doesn't work with PNGs.

**UPDATE**
I have just realized that this doesn't happen on every device. I've tried it on my Huawei P9 lite API 24 (real hardware) and it crashed, but on the 10.1 WXGA API 22 (AVD) it works.

Comment: Can you post your `my_background.xml` here?

Comment: It's right under `attrs.xml`

Comment: What theme do you use for your activity? To check if problem relates to theme you can add android:theme="@style/AppTheme.DARK" to the Checkbox in my_activity.xml

Comment: I have `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.DARK` in the application tag in the manifest

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution by myself. I don't know what exactly caused the exception, but this works:

`attrs.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <attr name="my_background" format="reference"/>
</resources>
```

`styles.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme.LIGHT" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="checkbox_background">@drawable/my_background_theme_light</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.DARK" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="checkbox_background">@drawable/my_background_theme_dark</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

`drawable/my_background_theme_light`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/my_png1_theme_light" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/png2_theme_light" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

`drawable/my_background_theme_dark`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/my_png1_theme_dark" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/png2_theme_dark" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```